# Odd (to me) Caliburn.Micro behaviour when project is 64bit

Tags: c#, 64-bit, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.Micro in our application and in 32 bit all works fine without compilation errors but as soon as we change the project to 64 bit we receive this for the App.xaml file :-

The name "ApplicationBootstrapper" does not exist in the namespace

```
clr-namespace:MyApp.Application.Bootstrapping.
```

The application, however, still runs.

Is it possible to run Caliburn.Micro is 64bit mode and, if so, are there any tweaks we need to perform to clear this "error"?

Edit :

Here is the App.xaml file :-

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.Application.App"   
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:Bootstrapping="clr-namespace:MyApp.Application.Bootstrapping">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Bootstrapping:ApplicationBootstrapper x:Key="ApplicationBootstrapper" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and here is the bootstrapper file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace MyApp.Application.Bootstrapping
{
    public class ApplicationBootstrapper : bootstrapper<MyApp.Application.MainWindow.MainWindowViewModel>
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: cant post is this comment as the code is too long - shall I create a new question?

Comment: You can _edit_ a question. Don't repost.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same but with x86 so the problem is not specify behaviour to x64. When you build the solution the problem disappears. So in my opinion error is only with not builded solution.